# Partial derivative of a CDF

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives

How to calculate this partial derivative? $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_{-\infty}^a(a-x)f(x)\text{d}x$$where $f(x)$ is a pdf.

Since I'm on the midway of a proof. So it will be great if the result is $a$. Is it?

Comment: This might help  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ denote the CDF connected with PDF $f$.

Then:
$$G(a):=\int_{-\infty}^{a}\left(a-x\right)f\left(x\right)dx=a\int_{-\infty}^{a}f\left(x\right)dx-\int_{-\infty}^{a}xf\left(x\right)dx=aF\left(a\right)-\int_{-\infty}^{a}xf\left(x\right)dx$$

If $f$ is a 'nice' function then taking the derivative leads to: $$G'(a)=F\left(a\right)+af\left(a\right)-af\left(a\right)=F\left(a\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain why $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}a}\int_{-\infty}^axf(x)\text{d}x=af(a)$?

Comment: Oh I figured it out. It is the second term in the formal statement of Leibniz integral rule in [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)